# How do I get the difference between a specific time and the current time in UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am wanting to have a countdown on a bot I am creating and am struggling to make it do this.

Simply, I want a time to be set in a variable (event) and there to be another variable with the current time in UTC (utcNow). I then want it to calculate the time until the event based on the current UTC time (event - utcNow).

Comment: So, what's the question? Is there some code you already have?

Comment: are you using a library or just pure JS?

Comment: You can do eventDate - utcNow if they both are JS Date objects.

Comment: Date objects are always UTC. Simply subtract one from the other and you get a difference in the UTC time value in milliseconds. You should be able to do `utcNow = Date.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now()` always returns a UTC time. Since you want the current time to be `utcNow` , just do `utcNow = Date.now()` .

Then create a new variable `event` and assign the date to it. You can also try

```
var event = new Date("<MONTH>, <YEAR> <TIME>");
event.setDate(x);
```

What you put in `x` is day.